# iPhone - Minimum KeySize (InBits) in RSA Algorithm for iOS using SecKeyGeneratePair

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, security, rsa

What is the minimum key size in RSA Algorithm for ios using SecKeyGeneratePair. When i tried to make it 256 it is throwing error SecKeyGeneratePair Error! -50 and it is working fine with 512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [SecKeyGeneratePair documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1395339-seckeygeneratepair) you can see that the minimum RSA key size it accepts is 512 bits.

However 512 bit RSA keys have been considered insecure for a long time: as of this writing, **the NIST recommended key length for RSA is 2048 bits**, see "[NIST Special Publication 800-57 Part 1: Recommendation for Key Management (Rev. 4)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-57pt1r4.pdf)" pages 53-56.

NIST estimates that 2048 bit RSA keys should last us through 2030.